# Query to get zero values from multiple rows and columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

i have the below data. How to query to get only zeros from all the rows and columns.

```
Timestamp  C1 C2 C3 C4
2012-05-17 1  0  1  0
2012-05-18 0  0  1  0
2012-05-19 1  0  0  1
2012-05-20 0  0  0  0
2012-05-21 0  1  0  0
```

The output should contains the timestamp,c1,c2,c3,c4 with 0 values. Please help!!

My original data is as below

```
Timestamp   TF  TA  TRIM    DG
17-05-2012  0   0.02    0   0.922
18-05-2012  0   0.03    0   0.831787611
19-05-2012  0.8 0.037   0   0.317744455
20-05-2012  0.9 0.06    0   0.56
21-05-2012  0   0.05    0   0.528702213
22-05-2012  0   0.078   0   0.428219784
23-05-2012  0   0.027   0   0.391674726
24-05-2012  0   0.09    0   0.826398887
```

I tried the below query

```
select timestamp,TF,TA,DG from temp where TF=0 and TF=0 and DG=0
```

But i am geting empty output with no rows and columns. i want the see all columns which has 0 as value with timestamp

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I need timestamp, C1,C2,C3,C4 columns with value 0.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: do want the row which has each of c1,c2,c3,c4 value as zero ?

Comment: @Reyaz: Please edit the question and show what the result set of the example will be, like this I do not understand the question.

Comment: Your explanation of your expected output isn't very clear - could you show it in the same way as you've given your sample data?

Comment: Hi Experts, i had modified my question. Could you please help me now to get the query.

Comment: Just to clarify TF = C1, TA = C2, TRIM = C3 and DG = C4? Also did you want the non zero values to be rounded up? i.e. 0.826398887 is rounded up to 1?

Comment: The Column names what you had mentioned is correct. And i DONT want to round up the values. i just need where all the 0's recorded for all the columns

Comment: Again, if you could post the *expected output* in the same way that you've given the *input*, we may have a better chance of understanding what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

just put the condition  in where clause

```
select * from table_name where  C1=0 or C2=0 or C3=0 or C4=0;
```

Answer (score 1):

use this query:

```
select timestamp,c1,c2,c3,c4
from table
where (c1 = 0 and c2 = 0 and c3 = 0 and c4 =0)
```

Comment: Hi Ajith, i tried the same query with my data(original data updated in my question) but i did not get any output.; i got nothing empty with only column names

Comment: that's because all the columns don't have 0's simultaneously .if you expect any one of the columns to have 0 then use OR instead of AND.

Comment: yes, i used it but i am getting 0.0246 values as i am expecting only 0 values. How to do that please?

Comment: are trying to round your values and get the o/p can you please provie sample data you want as o/p?

Comment: no i dont want to round the values. i need to find the only 0 values for all the columns with timestamp. 0.xx should not considered. Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM {table} where C1 = 0 and  C2 = 0 and C3= 0 and  C4= 0
```

If I got your question right.

Let's say your query had typo, and you actually wanted to check some other column beside TF twice. Can you post your table schematics? Maybe, by the sound of it, you are not dealing with decimal or some numeric type.

Comment: To provide an even better answer you should explain it in a few words. The OP seems to have a problem with the correct use of the columns.

Comment: I want to query the values only having 0's for all the columns with timestamps, like the sample out put i am expecting is below.  I am not including the excat values.

    timestamp  TF    TA   TRIM   DG
    17-05-2012  0    0     0      0
    18-05-2012  0    0     0      0
    19-05-2012  0    0     0      0

Comment: if your columns are numerical, and you are using SQL-SERVER then the query will output rows that in columns TF, TA, TRIM and DG have ONLY 0 will work. Either you are trying something diferent and you dont have a clue how to ask it, or you are pulling a stunt.

Comment: Sorry if i confused you. i have very huge data of 30,000 rows containing the decimal values that includes(0, 0.2, 1, 1.789, 1.6879 etc). I need a query to find where all 0's are located for all the columns with timestamp. And the zero values are not continues, it can be anywhere. Is it clear now?

Comment: ok, i made a test, check this link. and tell me what is wrong with it?? note, it isnt timestamp, it is varchar, due  i wanted to take your data and not current time on entry. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08555/2

Comment: thank you, the output you got is for only 1 date which all has zero values, but the timestamp 17-05-2012,18-05-2012 etc has TF values as 0, i need those as well in the output.

Comment: then where part should be where (TF= 0 and TA= 0 and TRIM = 0 and DG= 0) or TF = 0

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT * FROM <tablename> where C1 = 0 OR C2 = 0 OR C3= 0 OR C4= 0;
```

Edit - Based on your comment, I think this will work

```
SELECT [Timestamp], 
CASE WHEN TF>0 THEN 0 ELSE TF END AS TF,
CASE WHEN TA>0 THEN 0 ELSE TA END AS TA,
CASE WHEN DG>0 THEN 0 ELSE DG END AS DG
FROM <yourtable>
WHERE TF=0 OR TA=0 OR DG=0
```

The logic for this requirement is beyond my comprehension, though.

Raj

Comment: Using this i am getting the 0's and 0.045,0.4,0.9 values as well. But i need only 0's. How to achieve this?

Comment: Please post a sample output that you are expecting to see

Comment: Hi raj, i need the values with only 0's not 0.0X or 0.X(should not rounded). I need the output some thing like this. Below is not real data but this is an example
    Timestamp TF TA TRIM DG 
    17-05-2012 0 0 0 0 
    18-05-2012 0 0 0 0 
    19-05-2012 0 0 0 0

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you wanted the non-zero values to be rounded up:

```
select timestamp
    ,ceiling(tf) as c1
    ,ceiling(ta) as c2
    ,ceiling(trim) as c3
    ,ceiling(dg) as c4  
from table 
where tf=0 or ta=0 or trim=0 or dg=0
```

Comment: Sorry, i dont want non zero values to be rounded up. i need only zero values from the data, and the data has non zero values as well with decimal 0.9, 0.8 something like this, and my output should not contains these 0.9 and 0.8 as well, i need only zero values from the data